# What is the best way to store specific string on a website?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a browser extension that would allow me to highlight some string on a website. And I want this string to be highlighted whenever I open the same website again.

I can't just save the string to the database, because there might be many same strings on the website and I want to highlight just the one user specifically highlighted.

Saving and loading entire website seems like an overkill...

What is the best way to store specific string on a website?

Comment: See [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

Comment: try using an array: `[start of selection, length of selection]`